# Laravel Homestead. unable to run "homestead up"

Tags: laravel, terminal

I'm trying to get Laravel Homestead up and running. I've smoothly made it through all the step via http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead. The last thing I have to do is edit my homestead.yaml file (which I did) and run `homestead up`. But every time I try `homestead up` I get this output:

```
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/shared_helpers.rb:89:in `expand_path': couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/shared_helpers.rb:89:in `expand_path'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/shared_helpers.rb:89:in `user_data_path'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:16:in `user_plugins_file'
from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/manager.rb:27:in `instance'
from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/pre-rubygems.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix?

note: I'm a noob with terminal, I just started following tutorials on laracast, so my terminal is using Oh-my-zsh and Homebrew, that being said if possible a zsh or Homebrew syntax would be most helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some research this seems to be an error in version 2.0.8. A solution is to revert back to v2.0.7

First delete the current homestead 2.0.8 folder

`rm -rf ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead`

Then install Homestead v2.0.7

`composer global require laravel/homestead:v2.0.7`

Comment: latest is atm 2.0.8

and it introduces the same bug again.

Answer (score 6):

This answer from the [Laracasts forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/back-to-back-vagrant/replies/20424)  resolved it for me in Homestead 2.0.8:

> ..Turns out that the $_ENV array
>   isn't populated unless you explicitly state it in the php.ini. [...]
>
> To solve it, find the variables_order in your php.ini and add 'E' to
>   the string, like so: variables_order = "EGPCS".

Comment: While true, this was not sufficient for me. Reverting to 2.0.7 got me up and running.